# Random letters in the next line of printf after using function with malloc

Tags: c, string

I am trying to make a `function` in `C` which concatenates a `string` with a previously declared `string pointer`. For example it makes TestWord from Test + Word. Somehow when I `printf` the result the two words are successfully concatenated but in the next line I get a lot of `KKKKKKKKKKKKK` letters.

This is the function:

```
char* hozzafuz(char* elso_tag, char string[]){
    char *ptr = (char*)malloc( (strlen(elso_tag) + strlen(string) + 1) * sizeof(char));

    for(int i=0; i<strlen(elso_tag); i++){
        ptr[i]=elso_tag[i];
    }

    int index = 0;
    for(int i=strlen(elso_tag); i<(strlen(elso_tag) + strlen(string)); i++){
        ptr[i]=string[index++];
    }

    ptr[strlen(elso_tag) + strlen(string)] = '\n';
    free(elso_tag);
    return ptr;
}
```

I have made similar functions and all of them have the same problem. I think something is bad with the memory allocation.

Comment: You need space for the zero terminator ... and include it in `ptr`... so `malloc()` one more byte, and do `ptr[strlen(elso_tag) + strlen(string) + 1] = '\0';`

Comment: @pmg But i have already done it... Haven't I?

Comment: Where is `'\0'` in your code?

Comment: No, `\n` and `\0` are different. The first is a newline, the 2nd is the zero terminator. Maybe you meamt to use the zero terminator rather than newline... if that's what you intended, no need to tweak `malloc()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings in `c` are terminated by a `\0` character, and you need manually set it.

I'm not sure from the description if you meant to have a `\n` (newline character) at the end of the concatenated string or not. If not, you need to replace the `\n` assignment with a `\0`:

```c
ptr[strlen(elso_tag) + strlen(string)] = '\0';
```

If you do need it, you need to allocate an extra character and assign a `\0` to the last character:

```c
char* hozzafuz(char* elso_tag, char string[]){
    char *ptr = (char*)malloc( (strlen(elso_tag) + strlen(string) + 2) * sizeof(char));
    /* Note the extra character ------------------------------------^ */

    for(int i=0; i<strlen(elso_tag); i++){
        ptr[i]=elso_tag[i];
    }

    int index = 0;
    for(int i=strlen(elso_tag); i<(strlen(elso_tag) + strlen(string)); i++){
        ptr[i]=string[index++];
    }

    ptr[strlen(elso_tag) + strlen(string)] = '\n';
    ptr[strlen(elso_tag) + strlen(string) + 1] = '\0';
    free(elso_tag);
    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: This is why I already had +1 in malloc, for the NULL character.